# android how to use following code for Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to do an application for Fragments. I am doing an example code present at,

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

this example has 2 xml files. I unable get where should i use that xml files. And which class should be my main activity class.
Plz anybody help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the main activity is not given in the blog. As author says *"The code for this activity is not interesting; it just calls setContentView() with the given layout:".* 
So you have to create a dummy activity which just calls setContentView() with the Layout given in the first xml file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

where main.xml whould contain:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`TitleFragment` and `DetailsFragment` would go into seperate java files. 
The other xml and `DetailsActivity`is for handling Portrait mode in which case, the `DetailsFragment` is changed to a separate activity instead of a Fragment.

For more details refer the **Example** section of http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: where should i declare the 2nd xml?

Comment: I understood what they did. Instead of MainActivity extends Activity i gave it extends FragmentActivity. and its working.but i want depending landscape or potrait it shouldnt work. It should work depending upon sdk version. How can i do that?

Comment: Means if i run this app to a mobile then it ll work as different activity, if i put within a tab then it should come in the same page.

Comment: You can use [Compatibility Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), so that the same code works on older SDK as well.